# Calculating counts from statevector in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state

In Qiskit, how are counts calculated from statevectors ? For example ;

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
q = QuantumRegister(1,'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(1,'c')
a = 0.57045180
b = 0.82133108
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
circuit.initialize([a,b], 0)
circuit.h(q[0])
circuit.measure(q,c)
print(circuit)
job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=1024)
counts = job.result().get_counts()
circuit.save_statevector()
qobj = assemble(circuit)
state = backend.run(qobj).result().get_statevector()
print(counts)
print(state)
```

Results in ;

```
{'1': 32, '0': 992}
Statevector([ 1.-7.22699275e-17j, -0.+0.00000000e+00j],
            dims=(2,))
```

How counts are calculated from statevectors ? I mean when statevector has a value, for  single shot, how does it end up as an integer 1 or 0 (end state) ?

Answer (score 2):

The final state you are seeing in your circuit is either $|1\rangle$ or $|0\rangle$ is because you have already measured your circuit. Therefore, it will either project the state $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$ onto $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ depending on the probability of $|\alpha|^2$ or $|\beta|^2$.

If you remove the measurement out of your circuit then you will see the state $|\psi \rangle$ exactly:

```
q = QuantumRegister(1,'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(1,'c')
a = 0.57045180
b = 0.82133108
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q)
circuit.initialize([a,b], 0)
circuit.h(q[0])
print(circuit)
circuit.save_statevector()
qobj = assemble(circuit)
state = backend.run(qobj).result().get_statevector()
print('statevector:', state)


     ┌─────────────────────────────┐┌───┐
q_0: ┤ initialize(0.57045,0.82133) ├┤ H ├
     └─────────────────────────────┘└───┘
statevector: [ 0.98413911-7.11236623e-17j -0.17739844+7.11236623e-17j]
```

Now if you calculate $| 0.98413911-7.11236623e-17j|^2\cdot 1024 = 991.7745027395503
$ which is the reason why you see the $992$ counts in your `qasm_simulator` result. Similarly, $ |-0.17739844+7.11236623e-17j|^2\cdot 1024 = 32.22549147078 $ and so the reason for you to see the $32$ counts in your result.

There will be some offset when you run your simulation due to shot-noise but hope this help.